# Convert DD-MMM-YY to YYYY/MM/DD in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

DoB column in my dataset has date in the format below:

```
0       12-Jan-79
1       13-Jan-70
2       11-Mar-84
3       11-Mar-84
4       01-May-86
          ...    
1080    15-Mar-81
1081    07-Jul-96
1082    11-Apr-90
1083    22-Oct-64
1084    12-Jul-95
```

I need to convert the same into standard date format YYYY/MM/DD.

I tried `df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'])`. This is working fine for most of the cases.

**But in some instances like `22-Oct-64`, I can observe the data is converted into the future dates for example `2064-10-22`.**

I want to try something like `DoB.str[:-2]+'19'+DoB.str[-2:]` on entire column.

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125714/converting-series-to-pandas-datetime/61125840#61125840)

Comment: Not exactly. @QuangHoang

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change date format of pandas column (month-day-year to day-month-year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327249/change-date-format-of-pandas-column-month-day-year-to-day-month-year)

Comment: Nopes @lhdamiani

Comment: Can you share the data for which you get `2064-10-22`? Maybe that would be our starting point.

Comment: 22-Oct-64 @MayankPorwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective can be achieved by **cut the two characters**,**add 19** and then **paste the last two characters**.

```
df['DateOfBirth']

Out[14]:
0       12-Jan-79
1       13-Jan-70
2       11-Mar-84
3       11-Mar-84
4       01-May-86
          ...    
1080    15-Mar-81
1081    07-Jul-96
1082    11-Apr-90
1083    22-Oct-64
1084    12-Jul-95
Name: DateOfBirth, Length: 1085, dtype: object
```

Code: `df['DateOfBirth'] = df['DateOfBirth'].str[:-2]+'19'+df['DateOfBirth'].str[-2:]`

Output:

```
Out[16]:
0       12-Jan-1979
1       13-Jan-1970
2       11-Mar-1984
3       11-Mar-1984
4       01-May-1986
           ...     
1080    15-Mar-1981
1081    07-Jul-1996
1082    11-Apr-1990
1083    22-Oct-1964
1084    12-Jul-1995
Name: DateOfBirth, Length: 1085, dtype: object
```

Simply use `df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'])` to convert the columnn to datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the format:

```
df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'], '%d/%m/%y')
```

Comment: @GautamMishra: I tested it and it should work. You should say what error it gives.

Comment: I've similar requirement, when I tried the above mention soln got this error: ````ValueError: time data '18-Aug-08' does not match format '%d%m%y' (match)````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Take my sample df for example:

```
In [922]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[922]: 
         DOB
0  22/Oct/64

In [925]: df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])

In [927]: from datetime import timedelta, date

In [928]: future = df['DOB'] > date(year=2050,month=1,day=1)
In [930]: df.loc[future, 'DOB'] -= timedelta(days=365.25*100)

In [931]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[931]: 
         DOB
0 1964-10-22
```

**This will take care of the issues with future dates also.**

From the [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

> Year 2000 (Y2K) issues: Python depends on the platform’s C library, which generally doesn’t have year 2000 issues, since all dates and times are represented internally as seconds since the epoch. Function strptime() can parse 2-digit years when given %y format code. When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the POSIX and ISO C standards: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.

Comment: Makes sense. But can't this be achieved by slicing the string?

Comment: It's always a good idea to parse `date fields` as `datetime` rather than `str`.